# Can an Objective-c method be put into a C++ class?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Is it possible to declare an objective-c method in a C++ class?
For example:

```
class Piles {

public:
    int topIndexOf();
    void incrementTopIndex();
    void addCard();
    - (void)addImage:(); // <-- this
    .
    .
    .
```

}

Comment: Emphatically no. They're different languages.

Comment: Even if I'm using .hh, .mm, etc. (objective-C++) files?

Comment: what would be the point of this?

Comment: Because I'd like to give the method direct access to private members of the class.